# pytest mark parametrize: different assertion during each iteration

Tags: python, pytest

My apologies if this question probably is a duplicate, I searched similar question but without success finding anything related to my specific use case.

I am trying to make different assertions at different iteration of pytest parametrize inputs.

The code looks something like

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('file_paths',
                         [['script.py'],
                          ['script.py', 'script1.py', 'testdir/script2.py'],
                          ['', 'testdir']])
def test_save_file(project_explorer_with_files, file_paths):
    codes
    codes
    codes
    ...

    # if first iteration of file_paths:
        # make this assertion
    # if second iteration of file_paths:
        # make this assertion
    # if third iteration of file_paths:
        # make this assertion
```

Anyone can help me please how to achieve this!

Thanks in advance

I do not want to use len(file_paths) since probably in future the inputs might be changed for each sub-list

Comment: It looks like you should have separate tests with unique assertions and delegate to some common setup.

Answer (score 1):

Put some variable out of the function, somewhere is test data file or whatever and in function add +1, until it executing it will keep value up to date and will not re-read it every iteration, like:

```
var = 1;

@pytest.mark.parametrize('file_paths',
                         [['script.py'],
                          ['script.py', 'script1.py', 'testdir/script2.py'],
                          ['', 'testdir']])
def test_save_file(project_explorer_with_files, file_paths):
    codes
    codes
    codes
    ...
    if var == 1:
        # make this assertion
    if var == 2:
        # make this assertion
    if var == number_of_iteration:
        # make this assertion
    var+=1;
```

Comment: this tricks works in for loops! for functions `test_save_file.counter += 1` and `counter = 0` in the main scope after the function works. But the problem is that `project_explorer_with_files` is a fixture with parms which also makes the function get called several time! Therefore using  counter complicates things!! Thanks anyway.

Comment: sorry test_save_file.counter = 0

Answer (score 1):

You may consider adding ids to the mark.parametrize and then add request fixture to interogate the value.

```
@mark.parametrize('file_paths', [
    'a',
    'b',
    ], ids=['1', '2'])
def test_func(request, ...) 
    ...
    if request._pyfuncitem._genid == '1':
        <snip>
```

only caveat here is that ids have to be strings